# How to change the menu active link while scrolling?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll

I want to change the active class on my menu-items when scrolling down. When you scroll to the content that belongs to the menu-link, give that an active state (that will be styled in css). It's the same effect that Bootstrap is using with the [scrollspy plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy). However, I'm not using that same setup so I've tried several other scripts but I still can't get it to work. I'm using bootstrap 3 with the following code:

[Check out the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxsw45fd/3/)

HTML:

```
<div class="intro"><h1>Please scroll down</h1></div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="menu">
            <ul class="navigation">
                <li><a class="active" href="#one">One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
                <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
                <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
                <li><a href="#six">Six</a></li>
                <li><a href="#seven">Seven</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end of Menu -->

    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="content" class="col-md-10">
        <h2 id="one">One</h2>
        <p class="text"></p>
        <h2 id="two">Two</h2>
        <p class="text"></p>
        <h2 id="three">Three</h2>
        <p class="text"></p>
        <h2 id="four">Four</h2>
        <p class="text"></p>
        <h2 id="five">Five</h2>
        <p class="text"></p>
        <h2 id="six">Six</h2>
        <p class="text"></p>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
    <h2 id="seven">Seven</h2>
    <p class="text"></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}
.intro {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: olive;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
h1, h2 {
    padding: 40px 0 0;
    margin:0;
}
p.text {
    height: 700px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.active {
    background: pink;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why you can't use bootstrap's scrollspy?

Comment: Because I tried it serveral times and can't get it to work, maybe you can?

Comment: I've added an answer and a fiddle which shows it working with scrollspy. Hope this helps!

Comment: Same issue here. The point is that I'm using Blazor, and there are some behaviours related to anchors that prevent me from using scrollspy. For instance, `href` attribute can't hold an anchor on its own, you have to concat it with the absolute path by using `NavigationManager.Uri`; otherwise you get redirected to the root index page of your website (with an anchor targetting an element that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following to get it working with Bootstrap's scrollspy.

Add this CSS to use relative positioning for the body

```
body{
    position: relative; 
}
```

Add the following line of JS to specify the scrollspy target.

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#menu' })
```

Add the `nav` class to the menu  (scrollspy looks for an element with class nav inside the target).

```
<ul class="nav navigation">
```

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tunwe6we/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://api.jquery.com/scroll

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
   //yourcode
});
```

And down you have a demo, btw don't forget to add every element divs like:

```
<div class="box">
    <h1>H1</h1>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sxsw45fd/15/

I added step by step but you can create function.

I don't know why you want this if you use bootstrap you can simply use scrollspy as @ChaoticNadirs said.

Comment: Hi quead, thnx for your reaction. Call me dumb, but I tried it a lot of times with the scrollspy plugin but I can't get it to work. Maybe you can edit my fiddle with the scrollspy so it works? I'm trying for hours..